# Assigning to 'id<NSTextViewDelegate>' from incompatible type

Tags: objective-c, nstextview

I'm trying to assign a delegate for an NSTextView.

I added the protocol to my class in the interface header:

```
@interface myClass : NSViewController <NSTextDelegate>
```

and under the "viewDidLoad method, my the assignment looks like this:

```
self.stxtMyScrollTesxt.delegate = self;
```

did I miss something that I'm getting this warning?

> Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that it expects a type `NSTextViewDelegate` rather than `NSTextDelegate`.

So just change the line into

```
@interface myClass : NSViewController <NSTextViewDelegate>
```